# What is Non-Static Map from ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

This is what I received from my client:

> He needs to be able to interact with the map, enlarge certain
>   sections, etc.  Can you send this over in a non-static format?

What does this entail as I created a standard map for the company using ArcView 10.1.

Comment: The client only wanted to add text and color within the project boundary as needed. They can do that in JPEG or PDF/Adobe Pro. Thanks for the help Artwork.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure by what you mean "interact with map", and "enlarge certain sections".

**If the users wants to simply update map document scales and extents then:**

[Map Package](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Creating_a_map_package/006600000403000000/) will do the trick.  This includes map document and related data.  Map packages can be shared via ArcGIS Online, email, or ftp and extracted out to map document and related data source(s).  Users can make adjustments within the map document and re-package and share again between users.

**If the user wants a truly non static view of the data (for viewing or editing):**

Then you will have to host the data via a map service (WMS or WFS).